# MacOS, CMake and OpenMP

Tags: cmake, openmp

I am using the newest CMake (3.9.3) from Homebrew along with LLVM 5.0.0 also from Brew, because Clang here has OpenMP support.

This worked in CMake 3.8.2 with LLVM 5.

---

In my `CMakeLists.txt` I have

```
find_package( OpenMP )
```

and later I want to do

```
if( OpenMP_CXX_FOUND )
```

However CMake doesn't seem to pick up on the `find_package` directive.

I run CMake with

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DUSE_WERROR=ON
```

where I have checked that `clang` and `clang++` points correctly to `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang` and `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++`

All I get is these two lines:

```
-- Could NOT find OpenMP_C (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES) (found version "1.0")
-- Could NOT find OpenMP_CXX (missing: OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES) (found version "1.0")
```

If I set `OpenMP_C_FLAGS` myself (with `-DOpenMP_C_FLAGS=-fopenmp=libomp`) it changes the error to

```
-- Could NOT find OpenMP_C (missing: OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES) (found version "3.1")
```

Notice that it changes the version number, so it must be finding something, right?

What am I missing for this to work properly?

---

Okay, it seem that inside the `FindOpenMP.cmake` supplied by CMake we do a `try_compile`, which fails silently (because we do it a lot of times and most of them will fail, this makes sense). However, with Clang a `-Werror` flag is supplied, which fails because of an unused command line argument. I can thus add:

```
if(APPLE)
    if(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "Clang")
        set(OpenMP_C_FLAG "-fopenmp=libomp -Wno-unused-command-line-argument")
    endif()
    if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "Clang")
        set(OpenMP_CXX_FLAG "-fopenmp=libomp -Wno-unused-command-line-argument")
    endif()
endif()
```

to my project because I know that `-fopenmp=libomp` will work for this Clang.

Is this the right way of doing it?

Comment: Yes, LGTM. You could use the [imported targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/FindOpenMP.html) from then on to make your life a bit easier.

Answer (score 18):

The message basically tells you that you have to provide the path to the libraries and the names of the libraries. The following example should fix your problem (see also [find_package(OpenMP)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/FindOpenMP.html)). Note that I use the brew installation using the command "brew install llvm". The first four lines are just for completeness.

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/5.0.1/bin/clang")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/5.0.1/bin/clang++")
set(OPENMP_LIBRARIES "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/5.0.1/lib")
set(OPENMP_INCLUDES "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/5.0.1/include")

OPTION (USE_OpenMP "Use OpenMP to enable <omp.h>" ON)

# Find OpenMP
if(APPLE AND USE_OpenMP)
    if(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
        set(OpenMP_C "${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}")
        set(OpenMP_C_FLAGS "-fopenmp=libomp -Wno-unused-command-line-argument")
        set(OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES "libomp" "libgomp" "libiomp5")
        set(OpenMP_libomp_LIBRARY ${OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES})
        set(OpenMP_libgomp_LIBRARY ${OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES})
        set(OpenMP_libiomp5_LIBRARY ${OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES})
    endif()
    if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
      set(OpenMP_CXX "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")
      set(OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS "-fopenmp=libomp -Wno-unused-command-line-argument")
      set(OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES "libomp" "libgomp" "libiomp5")
      set(OpenMP_libomp_LIBRARY ${OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES})
      set(OpenMP_libgomp_LIBRARY ${OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES})
      set(OpenMP_libiomp5_LIBRARY ${OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES})
    endif()
endif()

if(USE_OpenMP)
  find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
endif(USE_OpenMP)

if (OPENMP_FOUND)
    include_directories("${OPENMP_INCLUDES}")
    link_directories("${OPENMP_LIBRARIES}")
    set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
    # set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
endif(OPENMP_FOUND)
```

You might want to set e.g. `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -lpthread")` such that the linker automatically detects the appropriate pthread library (see [pthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814698/how-can-i-add-a-flag-at-the-end-of-the-linking-command-line-using-cmake) and [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads)).

Answer (score 11):

Apparently, case is important. For an unrelated project I can make it work with

```
find_package ( OPENMP REQUIRED )
```

This didn't work:

```
find_package ( OpenMP REQUIRED )
```

With that directive, no need for setting all the other flags by hand.
cmake 3.13.2, clang-1000.11.45.5 (High Sierra)

Comment: Sadly, this did not do it for me.

Comment: This gets rid of the package not found error, but now the target OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX is no longer found. Changing that to all caps doesn't help.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe it's a CMake version thing, I come up with a slightly different solution with [Franzi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48216682/5335565).

I also use `brew install libomp` on my machine. It seems like `OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS` is used for compiling project source code instead of compiling the omp (the flag is stored in the omp target and will be populated by command `target_link_libraries`).

Besides that, `OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES` shouldn't have prefix `lib` because it will cause an error like `-llibomp` not found, where `-lomp` should be used instead.

I also noticed that `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID` is `AppleClang` instead of `Clang` if I put `project(playground)` after `cmake_minimum_required`. In reverse, it's `Clang`, quite annoying and I don't know why.

`Xpreprocessor` used here is because apple clang doesn't ship with OpenMP and this flag tells the compiler to look for pragma (preprocessor expansion) elsewhere. In our case, it's the header files in the include path where the libomp is installed.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(playground)

if(APPLE)
    set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)

    if(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang\$")
        set(OpenMP_C_FLAGS "-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp")
        set(OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES "omp")
        set(OpenMP_omp_LIBRARY omp)
    endif()

    if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang\$")
        set(OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS "-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp")
        set(OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES "omp")
        set(OpenMP_omp_LIBRARY omp)
    endif()

endif()

find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)

add_executable(helloworld helloworld.cxx)
target_link_libraries(helloworld PRIVATE OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
```

Here's my helloworld

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <thread>
#include <sstream>

int main(void)
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
      std::stringstream ss;
      ss << std::this_thread::get_id();
      printf("%s, Hello, world.\n", ss.str().c_str());
    }

  return 0;
}
```

output is,

```
0x700002dc8000, Hello, world.
0x10a17d5c0, Hello, world.
0x7000045d1000, Hello, world.
0x7000055d7000, Hello, world.
0x700005dda000, Hello, world.
0x7000035cb000, Hello, world.
0x7000065dd000, Hello, world.
0x700003dce000, Hello, world.
0x700007de6000, Hello, world.
0x700004dd4000, Hello, world.
0x7000075e3000, Hello, world.
0x700006de0000, Hello, world.
```

Comment: The whole if(APPLE) block is unnecessary: CMake can detect the correct OpenMP options for Apple Clang and standard Clang.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. Strange, in another project I didn't need to do this and it found OpenMP fine. Yet when I created a small test to see if I could consistently build with OpenMP, find_package() couldn't find OpenMP anymore. Same arguments to -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER, same environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

With recent versions of CMake (3.18, didn't work with 3.14) and a fresh installation of MacOS (with developer CL tools installed, of course), `brew install libomp` was the only action needed to make things work.

Comment: did you install macOS BigSur?

Comment: @nac001 yes I did

Comment: brew install libomp works for me

Answer (score 0):

MacOS Ventura

cmake: /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.25.1
OpenMP: /usr/local/Cellar/libomp/15.0.7
llvm: /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/15.0.7_1

above solution worked after setting compiler directories and libomp directories to the correct values

with the change:

set(OpenMP_C_FLAGS "-fopenmp=libomp")

for both the clang and clangxx sections