# OpenMP 4.5 on Windows with Clang, CMake & Ninja

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, clang, openmp

I am trying to use OpenMP 4.5 on Windows but MSVC seems to not support OpenMP > 2.0

I found that Clang supports OpenMP 4.5 but I can't make it work on Windows.

I have Visual Studio 2017, Clang 8.0.0 and CMake 3.13 installed.

To build my CMake project, I call:

```
cmake .. -G Ninja -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang-cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang-cl.exe" -DCMAKE_LINKER:PATH="C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/lld-link.exe"
```

But it cannot find OpenMP :

```
-- Could NOT find OpenMP_C (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES)
-- Could NOT find OpenMP_CXX (missing: OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES)
-- Could NOT find OpenMP (missing: OpenMP_C_FOUND OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
```

If I build using **clang alone** (clang.exe & clang++.exe instead of clang-cl.exe), it finds Clang's OpenMP lib (OpenMP 5.0)

If I build using **MSVC alone**, it finds OpenMP 2.0

But using **clang-cl.exe**, it does not find OpenMP (neither version)

Is there a way to get OpenMP 4.5 working on Windows ?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use the 1st solution you mention (clang alone). Apparently it works for you and OpenMP 5 is a super-set of OpenMP 4.5... So why not?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted an example of your CMake, so I'm going off of conjecture here. If you are using `find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)`, I have also received similar errors when using `clang-cl` from Visual Studio. There are known [limitations](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19404) with CMake's `FindOpenMP.cmake` module, as well as some lack of support the `clang-cl` side. There are other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48216682/3987854) on this site suggesting to populate the CMake `OpenMP_` variables manually, but this seems backwards, and I only have limited success. I was able to successfully run CMake then compile my applications with MSVC+Clang by avoiding the use of `find_package` and (unfortunately) hard-coding the path to the OpenMP libraries for now:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)
project(MyOpenMPTest LANGUAGES CXX)

set(OpenMP_LIBRARY_DIR "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/Llvm/lib")
set(OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS "-Xclang -fopenmp")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")

# Tell CMake where to find the OpenMP libraries.
link_directories(${OpenMP_LIBRARY_DIR})

# Library
add_library(MyLibrary SHARED MyExample.h MyExample.cpp)
# Link in the OpenMP libraries.
target_link_libraries(MyLibrary PUBLIC libomp libiomp5md)

# Executable
add_executable(MyOpenMpTest MyOpenMpTest .cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyOpenMpTest MyLibrary)
```

Hopefully, the folks at CMake and LLVM will get this issue worked out soon and `FindOpenMP.cmake` can be used more reliably.