# OpenMP CMake Apple

Tags: macos, makefile, cmake, openmp

I am currently trying to compile a project on Mac using cmake, but running into trouble. I have already looked at this article [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46414660/macos-cmake-and-openmp), but am still running into some trouble. My CMakeLists.txt looks as follows.

```
project(tpch_framework)

# enable c++11
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/10.0.0_3/bin/clang")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/10.0.0_3/bin/clang++")
set(OPENMP_LIBRARIES "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/10.0.0_3/lib")
set(OPENMP_INCLUDES "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/10.0.0_3/include")

OPTION (USE_OpenMP "Use OpenMP to enamble <omp.h>" ON)

# Find OpenMP
if(APPLE AND USE_OpenMP)
    if(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
        set(OpenMP_C_FLAGS "-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp")
        set(OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES "omp")
        set(OpenMP_omp_LIBRARY omp)
    endif()
    if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
        set(OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS "-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp")
        set(OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES "omp")
        set(OpenMP_omp_LIBRARY omp)
    endif()
endif()

if(USE_OpenMP)
  find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
endif(USE_OpenMP)

if (OPENMP_FOUND)
    include_directories("${OPENMP_INCLUDES}")
    link_directories("${OPENMP_LIBRARIES}")
    set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS} -libomp")
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS} -libomp")
    set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
endif(OPENMP_FOUND)

# Configure required Boost libraries
set(BOOST_ROOT "" CACHE PATH "Boost build root (useful on Windows)")
option(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS
       "Search for static boost libs" OFF)
option(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED
       "Search for multithreaded boost libs" ON)
option(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME
       "Search for boost libs linked against static C++ runtime" OFF)
find_package(Boost 1.47.0 REQUIRED filesystem system)

# ensure that dependant libraries not explicitly specified here
# are found by the linker:
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
 
#Bring the headers into the project
include_directories(include)
  
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE INC_ALL "include/*.hpp")

#However, the file(GLOB...) allows for wildcard additions:
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")
 
add_library(tpch_framework ${SOURCES})
add_executable(framework main.cpp ${INC_ALL})
target_link_libraries(framework tpch_framework)
#target_link_libraries(framework stdc++fs)
target_link_libraries(framework ${LIBS})
```

When I execute this, I get the following output.

```
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 11.0.0.11000033
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 11.0.0.11000033
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc - works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ - works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenMP_C: -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp  
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp  
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE   
-- Found Boost: /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.72.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.72.0", minimum required is "1.47.0") found components: filesystem system 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/...
```

However, when I then use make, I get the following error.

```
/Users/myname/Desktop/Uni/MHD/tpch_framework_challenge_mhd_2020/src/task4.cpp:48:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'omp_set_num_threads'
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
```

Which I am guessing comes, as I get this warning: `clang-10: warning: -libomp: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]`.

Does anybody have any ideas? I have been stuck with this for way too long and would appreciate any tips.

Kind regards,
Moritz

Comment: What version of CMake are you using? From your Lists file it looks like you're using 2.x, which is almost a decade old at this point!

Comment: `cmake version 3.17.0` I just don't have much experience using cmake and was going off of what I was given and made some adjustments from what I found on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use a recent version of CMake, this build should work.

```
# NOTE: Every top-level CMakeLists.txt must start with these two lines
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(tpch_framework)

## Enable C++14
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

## Find dependencies

# OpenMP
find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)

# Boost
set(BOOST_ROOT "" CACHE PATH "Boost build root (useful on Windows)")
option(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS
       "Search for static boost libs" OFF)
option(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED
       "Search for multithreaded boost libs" ON)
option(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME
       "Search for boost libs linked against static C++ runtime" OFF)
find_package(Boost 1.47.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem system)

## Add main project targets

# NOTE: This is completely wrong and will break incremental builds after
#       doing a "git pull" or similar. You should never glob for source
#       files, but instead list them explicitly.
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")
 
add_library(tpch_framework ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(tpch_framework PUBLIC BUILD_INTERFACE:include)
target_link_libraries(tpch_framework
                      PUBLIC
                      OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX
                      Boost::boost 
                      Boost::filesystem
                      Boost::system)

add_executable(framework main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(framework PRIVATE tpch_framework)
```

There is *so* much bad CMake advice here on SO and in tutorials, it's a real shame.

Comment: Hey Alex. Thanks for your help, but sadly it didn't work, I'm getting the following output:
```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:39 (add_executable):
  Target "framework" links to target "OpenMP::OpenMP" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (add_library):
  Target "tpch_framework" links to target "OpenMP::OpenMP" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

Comment: I believe, that the key is the warning mentioned at the end of the question `clang-10: warning: -libomp: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]`, as small test program needs this flag to compile. Any thoughts?

Comment: Oops. Should be OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX

Comment: Thanks, however now I'm getting the same error as before 
`error: use of undeclared identifier 'omp_set_num_threads'
omp_set_num_threads(4);`
How could I explicitly add flags `-Xpreprocessor -lomp`?

Comment: That flag makes no sense. That would pass a linker flag, `-lomp` to the preprocessor, which would do nothing and would probably generate a warning or error. Maybe even the warning you refer to above...

Comment: Can you post the actual compiler command line that CMake is running?

Comment: The thing is, when I compile my test file without that second flag I get the following error `g++ test.cpp -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___kmpc_fork_call", referenced from:
      _main in test-948209.o
  "_omp_get_thread_num", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined. in test-948209.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: I always run 
CC=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/bin/gcc-9
CXX=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.3.0_1/bin/g++-9
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release CMakeLists.txt 
make

Beforehand I delete the CMakeCache.txt and do a make clean.

Comment: So you should definitely be doing out-of-tree builds. The output in your question shows you're not using gcc, which doesn't need the `-Xpreprocessor` flag (which AppleClang does). If you can delete all the CMake-generated files and try again maybe I can help you further. We can also take this to chat, or you can find me on the [CppLang Slack](https://cpplang.now.sh/)

Comment: I just tried the CMake build above on my mac with both AppleClang 10 and the same version of GCC and both worked. So there's probably something wrong with your environment.

Comment: @MoritzRuge, GCC uses a different OpenMP runtime, called `libgomp`. OpenMP code produced by GCC shouldn't be referencing `__kmpc_fork_call`, which is a function in the LLVM OpenMP runtime.

Comment: @HristoIliev it looks like compilers are getting mixed.

Comment: Deleting all files created by CMake did the trick. The code now compiles and I see a speedup in my code. Thanks so much for the help, it's really appreciated.

Comment: Glad it worked out! If my answer was indeed helpful, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it.